# Check if value doesn't exist in JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to check if a value doesn't exist in the given object, by filtering an array of string.

I want to check if the values in the `keys` array are contained in the JSON object I'm looping. If one of the values isn't, I have to do something else, but only if the non-existent value (in `resArray`) is contained in the `keys` array.

[JSON here](http://pastebin.com/9RgHjjZ9)

Here's what I tried:

```
var keys = [
    "total_kills",
    "total_deaths",
    "total_planted_bombs",
    "total_defused_bombs",
    "total_kills_knife",
    "total_kills_headshot",
    "total_wins_pistolround",
    "total_wins_map_de_dust2",
    "last_match_wins",
    "total_shots_fired",
    "total_shots_hit",
    "total_rounds_played",
    "total_kills_taser",
    "last_match_kills",
    "last_match_deaths",
    "total_kills_hegrenade",
  ];

  var resArray = stats.playerstats.stats;
  var statsArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < resArray.length; j++){

        //if the value in keys array exists, do something
        if(resArray[j]["name"] === keys[i]){
         //do something
       }
       if(<value doesn't exist)>)
         //do something else.
    }
  }
```

## Solved:

```
function contains(obj, key, value) {
        return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === value;
      } 

      var resArray = stats.playerstats.stats;
      var statsArray = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {

        resArray.some(function(found){

          if(contains(found, "name", keys[i])){

            statsArray.push(found);

          }

        });

        if(typeof statsArray[i] == 'undefined'){

          console.log("Not present in array: " + keys[i]);
          statsArray.push({"name": keys[i], "value": 'None'});

        }
      }
```

Thanks to everyone has replied to this thread.

Comment: Look up `hasOwnProperty()`

Comment: can be achieved using a combination of array methods like `filter` and/or `includes` and/or `indexOf` - other stuff depends on the contents of `resArray` - which you haven't really explained or given an example of

Comment: @JaromandaX if you look at the json link I left in the page, you can find what you are searching for.

Comment: yes, if I could read, that would be a good thing :p (sorry)

Comment: `new RegExp("(\\b("+keys.join(")(")+")\\b)").test(resArray[j].name)`... avoid outer loop. make rx before looping for best speed...

Comment: Your question shouldn't depend on links to other sites. Put all relevant info directly in the question itself, reduced yet complete enough to provide sufficient information.

Comment: Please educate yourself on what JSON is. It's a string-based format for exchanging information, such as with a server. What you have is a plain old JavaScript object.

Comment: Don't point to external resources. Include all the necessary information within the question itself. Also, you are requested to provide a **minimal** example. That means we don't need an array with 15 elements, or a "JSON" with 100. Also, please indicate what, if anything, is NOT WORKING in the code you provided, and what the results were of your attempt to debug the logic.

Comment: Please remove "Solved" from your title and post the solution you found as a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your example insinuates that you're creating a new array based off the stats and conditional presence of your provided keys. An easy way to build this array would be to use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to enumerate over your stats array. Next, in each iteration's callback you can pass the `name` property as an argument to [`keys.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to check if that particular `name` is present in your `keys` array.

```
var statsArray = stats.map(function(stat) {
  if (keys.indexOf(stat.name) > -1) {
    return stat;
  } else {
    return stat.name + ' not found.';
  }
});
```

This will yield a new array which will contain either the stat object or a not regarding its absence in keys. However, you can return whatever your heart desires, as long as it's a valid array item.

Here's a working example with a small chunk of your dataset (but will work with your original dataset):

```js
var keys = [
  "total_kills",
  "total_deaths",
  "total_planted_bombs",
  "total_defused_bombs",
  "total_kills_knife",
  "total_kills_headshot",
  "total_wins_pistolround",
  "total_wins_map_de_dust2",
  "last_match_wins",
  "total_shots_fired",
  "total_shots_hit",
  "total_rounds_played",
  "total_kills_taser",
  "last_match_kills",
  "last_match_deaths",
  "total_kills_hegrenade",
];

var stats = [{
  "name": "total_kills",
  "value": 25305
}, {
  "name": "total_deaths",
  "value": 27474
}, {
  "name": "total_time_played",
  "value": 1822419
}, {
  "name": "total_planted_bombs",
  "value": 1397
}, {
  "name": "total_defused_bombs",
  "value": 239
}, {
  "name": "total_wins",
  "value": 11477
}, {
  "name": "total_damage_done",
  "value": 3783962
}, {
  "name": "total_money_earned",
  "value": 65159500
}, {
  "name": "total_rescued_hostages",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_knife",
  "value": 278
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_hegrenade",
  "value": 168
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_glock",
  "value": 699
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_deagle",
  "value": 1289
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_elite",
  "value": 37
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_fiveseven",
  "value": 165
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_xm1014",
  "value": 78
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_mac10",
  "value": 154
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_ump45",
  "value": 330
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_p90",
  "value": 1105
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_awp",
  "value": 6934
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_ak47",
  "value": 4528
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_aug",
  "value": 137
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_famas",
  "value": 540
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_g3sg1",
  "value": 116
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_m249",
  "value": 50
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_headshot",
  "value": 7112
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_enemy_weapon",
  "value": 2308
}, {
  "name": "total_wins_pistolround",
  "value": 843
}, {
  "name": "total_wins_map_cs_assault",
  "value": 9
}, {
  "name": "total_wins_map_cs_italy",
  "value": 15
}, {
  "name": "total_wins_map_cs_office",
  "value": 11
}, {
  "name": "total_wins_map_de_aztec",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "name": "total_wins_map_de_cbble",
  "value": 373
}, {
  "name": "total_wins_map_de_dust2",
  "value": 4857
}, {
  "name": "total_wins_map_de_dust",
  "value": 25
}, {
  "name": "total_wins_map_de_inferno",
  "value": 777
}, {
  "name": "total_wins_map_de_nuke",
  "value": 247
}, {
  "name": "total_wins_map_de_train",
  "value": 47
}, {
  "name": "total_weapons_donated",
  "value": 2466
}, {
  "name": "total_broken_windows",
  "value": 30
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_enemy_blinded",
  "value": 566
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_knife_fight",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "name": "total_kills_against_zoomed_sniper",
  "value": 2284
}, {
  "name": "total_dominations",
  "value": 270
}, {
  "name": "total_domination_overkills",
  "value": 225
}, {
  "name": "total_revenges",
  "value": 207
}, {
  "name": "total_shots_hit",
  "value": 83704
}, {
  "name": "total_shots_fired",
  "value": 399207
}, {
  "name": "total_rounds_played",
  "value": 23419
}, {
  "name": "total_shots_deagle",
  "value": 12137
}, {
  "name": "total_shots_glock",
  "value": 21299
}, {
  "name": "total_shots_elite",
  "value": 777
}, {
  "name": "total_shots_fiveseven",
  "value": 3385
}, {
  "name": "total_shots_awp",
  "value": 22667
}];

var statsArray = stats.map(function(stat) {
  if(keys.indexOf(stat.name) > -1) {
    return stat;
  } else {
    return stat.name + ' not present in keys';
  }
});

console.log(statsArray);
```

Comment: You have access to the stat within the callback so just `return stat.name;`

Comment: But what if the value is missing in the "stats" array and given in the "keys" array?

Comment: That would mean that the current stat isn't whitelisted. You can return a note regarding it being missing from your keys. I've updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by using a combination of array functions. For example:

```
let stats = data.playerstats.stats;
let matches = stats.filter(i => keys.indexOf(i.name) >= 0);
let matchKeys = matches.map(k => k.name);
let negatives = keys.filter(i => matchKeys.indexOf(i) < 0);
```

Then you can just loop through the matches/negatives to do what you want with them.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gn05t2nv/).